Adding a RequiredFieldValidator causes the 'jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js' error
I have a problem inside an asp net application where I get the 'jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js' error when I try to add an asp:RequiredFieldValidator element inside an UserControl
I tried installing AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery and AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined but nothing changed, I don't get this error on any other project, this project uses .NET 4.7.2 and jquery 3.7.1.
Is there something I am doing wrong? what can I try?

This often suggests that the page does not have jQuery installed correctly.
However, you can in web config force the client side validation to revert to pre HTML5 code, and I often done this.
Hence, in web.config, try this setting:
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>

However, I would double check that the page in question has jQuery working.
If jQuery is not found, then a post-back will occur, and the validator will run server side and display it's message.

Editing the appsettings worked, however I tried checking for the jquery and I don't get any error saying that is not found, I included it on my master page, just like other projects that I worked on, I tried including it on both the user control and the page that uses it

With that setting, then client side javascript doesn't require jquery and doesn't require html5. No worries

Could this cause some issues with other scripts that I could use in future?

No, you should be fine.  Even adopting and using jquery in such pages should be fine.
